# Does a tcp socket hungry program interfere with filesystem I/O

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, file-descriptor

I'm using autobench to test performance of two different php scripts. Only one of them has some filesystem I/O.

The problem is that I can't run autobench on a different host than webserver so I fear my benchmarks could be wrong.

Does autobench (configured to open thousands of connection) interfere with filesystem I/O?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as sockets and files both use file descriptors to represent themselfs if opened. And the number of file descriptors it limited.

Search `man proc` for `file-max` for details.

Comment: Ok it is as I was suspecting. Could tuning /proc/sys/fs/file-max (and /proc/sys/fs/inode-max) improve performances making benchmarks reliable?

Comment: @Fabio Buda: To a certain point, depending on the over all system resource available: yes

Answer (score 0):

It interferes, of course. Place where these two programs collide is in linux kernel. Linux kernel can do limited quantity of system calls.